# Are the constituents of the known universe matter (including antimatter) and electromagnetic radiation?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, cosmology, universe, antimatter, matter

Is it correct to say that the constituents of the known universe are matter (including antimatter) and electromagnetic radiation, leaving aside the comparatively hypothetical ‘dark’ entities? This is just an attempt to come up with a valid generalisation. If not, I would be grateful to know why and what would be the nearest possible correct statement of the same context.

Comment: Are you including gravitational energy as a component of matter?

Comment: This is included in what I am trying to understand. Is gravitational energy a component of matter?

Answer (score 1):

It is not entirely correct to say the non-dark universe is matter and electromagnetic radiation, but it is a decent approximation.

[Peebles and Fukugita have a very useful paper where they give an inventory](https://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/0406095). Leaving out the "dark sector", we can see that of the primordial thermal radiation (about 0.1% of the total mass-energy budget) much of it is in the form of neutrinos which might count as matter (but aren't baryonic). Of the 4.5% that is baryonic mass, a 0.15% fraction is in the form of black holes - whether to say that is matter is a (ahem) matter of definition. To most non-astronomers black holes likely do not count as "matter".

A fraction $10^{-7.5}$ of the total is gravitational radiation, which definitely does not fall into your categories. There is also $10^{-8}$ in the form of kinetic energy of the intergalactic medium - a small fraction, but a vast amount of energy.

So while the non-dark sector is *mostly* baryonic matter and electromagnetism, there is some things that are more gravitational.

Comment: Thank you, Anders. The material by Peebles and Fukugita is comprehensive and I will try to go through the details, as much as I can. Your pointed summary is very helpful and also includes the answer to my question about gravitational energy  in the comments above.

Answer (score 0):

> the constituents of the known universe are matter (including its anti-counterpart) and electromagnetic radiation

It is better, for general purposes, to think of the sole constituent of the universe as *energy*.  Energy can come in different forms : matter, EM radiation and the hypothetical dark matter and dark energy.  But it's all energy and, subject to some basic rules and restrictions to match the way the universe we see works (which are beyond the scope of your question) you can convert energy in one form to other forms.

Comment: Thank you, Stephen. It is a tempting generalisation for anyone well versed in expressing all relevant relationships involving energy. Being fully conscious of the deficiencies of my rather conservative learning of the subject, it is not easy for me to transition away from the ‘energy of …’ towards the ‘energy itself’ mindset. Will take some extra effort, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

[This graphic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universe#/media/File:Universe_content_bar_chart.svg) from Wikipedia compares the composition of the visible universe in the current era with its composition 380,000 years after the Big Bang, which we know from analysing the [cosmic microwave background](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_microwave_background). Composition in the current era is roughly $70\%$ dark energy, $25\%$ dark matter and $4.9\%$ ordinary matter. Electromagnetic radiation and antimatter fit into the remaining $0.1\%$.